# Is the smoked ham safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety

I cooked a small boneless smoked ham after wrapping in foil about 2 hours and forgot and left it in the oven for about 12 hours after turning off the oven.  Then I put it in fridge. Is it safe to eat?

Answer (score 0):

Perishable food left at room temperature (such as a turned off oven) for more than about 2 hours should be discarded.   The ham has well exceeded that time.